# Getting error NG0901 in ngfor loop in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to render options inside select field by using defined array in ts file as below. My angular version is 13

```
roles = [
{ id: 0, name: "Perfect" },
{ id: 1, name: "Low" },
{ id: 2, name: "Minor" },
{ id: 3, name: "High" }
];
```

My HTML code as below

```
<select>
 <ng-template *ngFor="let role of roles">
  {{role?.name}}
 </ng-template>
</select>
```

But I'm getting this error inside my browser console

```
ERROR Error: NG0901
   at e.find (main.js:1:989143)
   at P.ngDoCheck (main.js:1:778652)
   at qi (main.js:1:828777)
   at Fi (main.js:1:828549)
   at ms (main.js:1:828269)
   at Vf (main.js:1:862353)
   at Module.Wf (main.js:1:862198)
   at Z (1410.js:1:8251)
   at md (main.js:1:866002)
   at iu (main.js:1:864654)
```

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71027327/why-am-i-getting-a-ng0901-error-when-i-am-not-performing-any-data-change)

I was able to find solutions as above but those describe the error is because of users have use *ngfor for render the Json objects instead of the arrays.

Since I'm using the array already, but I'm bit confused about those solutions.

Comment: `NG0901` is only the error code. Can you provide with the whole error message? 'Cause I don't see any problem with this code. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fgteo9?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: @Demo I have posted the whole error. no any other errors in console

Comment: You need to provide us with a reproducible example in order for us to help you solve the problem. As you see above, I'm not having this issue in my example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `ng-container` instead of `ng-template`

Hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

*ngFor directive inside a  element, which is not allowed. To fix this error, you should move the *ngFor directive to the  element like this:

```
select>
  <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role.id">{{role.name}}</option>
</select>
```