# How can I find the ngFor that's throwing an NG0901 error?

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, ngfor

My Angular app is throwing errors that look like this:

```
ERROR Error: NG0901
at r.find (main.js:23:776914)
at ne.ngDoCheck (main.js:23:613563)
at oe (main.js:23:670651)
at tt (main.js:23:670807)
at $ (main.js:23:670552)
at j (main.js:23:670274)
at $m (main.js:23:703235)
at Object.Gm (main.js:23:703079)
at UT (main.js:1:1668916)
at Km (main.js:23:705139)
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71028391/399649), this happens when an `*ngFor` tries to iterate over an object that isn't an array. My problem is there are over a hundred components on the page, and I have no idea which one is throwing the error. If there's a visibly broken ngFor somewhere, I can't see it. The links in the stack trace all point to generated code, none of it helpful. Is there any other way to tell which ngFor is breaking?

Comment: I don't know if this will work for you in this case, but occasionally when I get some incomprehensible error I actually look at the generated code (main.js in this case) with NotePad++. Even though the .js code is generated and bears little resemblance to the underlying TypeScript, you can sometimes identify the area of the code that it was generated from by looking for string literals, and so on, in the vicinity of the location.

Comment: I understand that you have a `find` (possible in a ngDoCheck) in an array that it's null. Check in your code where you use `find`

Comment: What version of `Angular` are you working on? I ask this because if you are using version 12 or higher then `strict mode` should be enabled by default and it should complain either in the component ts file or template where the issue is, unless everything within the ts component has `any` as type... If `strict mode` is disabled then you could enable it temporarily and see if it highlights where the issue is

Comment: @Eliseo - I'll look for one, thank you.

Comment: @Andres2142 - I'm on 16. I don't see any complaints in the template, but unfortunately the code is way too liberal with `any` for my taste.